# How does the delegation model of class loaders ensure that unique classes are loaded?

Tags: java, classloader

I had been reading about the 'uniqueness' feature of the delegation model of class loaders in Java:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-classloaders#uniqueness

I didn't understand, how in the absence of such a model would we run a risk of non-unique classes being loaded?

When class loaders use fully qualified class names to load them, how can we end up loading duplicate classes, specially when we check whether or not a class has been loaded before delegating the task to parent loader?

https://www.baeldung.com/java-classloaders#classloader-work

Comment: One fact with classes is that when they're loaded by different class loaders, they are different Class instances. In this sense, the FQN does not help.

Comment: Think of how classloaders for WAR files are implemented: the specification requires WAR deployments to be isolated so there's a classloader for each of them. They could contain the same classes e.g. those belonging to frameworks. However, delegation would ensure that classes like `java.lang.String` are loaded by the root classloader and thus are not duplicated within the JVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can we end up loading duplicate classes, specially when we check whether or not a class has been loaded before delegating the task to parent loader? https://www.baeldung.com/java-classloaders#classloader-work

The step where the class loader checks whether or not a class has been loaded, i.e. [method `java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#findLoadedClass(java.lang.String)), does not imply uniqueness. Imagine two class loaders, `CL1` and `CL2`, both loading a class `X`. In that case, if `CL1` loaded `X` before `CL2`, then the check done by `CL2` will *not* return the same class loaded by `CL1`, because these class loaders do not share this information between them.

The delegation model is what "shares" this information via the parent class loader.

Comment: Thanks...this was helpful

Comment: The exact details are given in [JVMS, §5.3. Creation and Loading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3). It might not be an easy read, but it’s precise and authoritative. The articles on baeldung.com have mixed quality. The single byte copying loop found in the example code of the linked article, for example, is something sane programmers should not copy.

Comment: @Holger "It might not be an easy read" in bold, please. It is good that we have users like you that take pride in _properly_ explaining these things in answers.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have 2 jar files, each containing class `com.example.Foo`.

Say the jar files are loaded by 2 different classloaders, with loader1 being parent of loader2.

Whether we're running with loader1 or with loader2 as the active classloader, we will always get the class from loader1. The class in the second jar file will never be loaded, hence uniqueness is guaranteed, i.e. we will not have 2 classes with the same name in memory.

---

*FYI:* The Servlet specification violates that delegation model, and would load the class from loader2 if it is the active classloader. That has been know to cause trouble, especially with the old Apache Commons Logging library (version 1).